# Installing older version of Elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, homebrew

Running `brew install elasticsearch@2.0.0`, I'm getting:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "elasticsearch@2.0.0" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
   git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
==> Searching local taps...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

How do I go about installing elasticsearch@2.0.0 in my Rails App.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Homebrew does not currently support 2.0.0 of Elasticsearch. If you run:

```
brew search elasticsearch
```

You will see the currently supported version of Elasticsearch that homebrew allows you to install. At the time of this question, the only version in the 2.x series that is supported by homebrew is 2.4.

If you **must** have 2.0.0, you can always [download it directly](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/elasticsearch-2-0-0) and install it yourself. You can just download the version during your install script and run the install commands.

If you **must** use 2.0.0 and you **must** user homebrew, you can always create a custom formula. Just run the command:

```
brew create <url to zip>
```

Then you modify the resulting ruby file to run the correct install commands (*hint*: you can copy from the 2.4 formula).